# Integrating Salesforce with Plaid

Tags: triggers, salesforce, integration, apex, plaid

I have a requirement where I need to integrate Salesforce with Plaid. Need to store Bank statement in an Object in Salesforce by using Plaid.
I have created "Site" in Salesforce. In Visualforce Page, I need to hold the Plaid code.
I don't have any idea regarding Front end mechanism. I mean can any one suggest what i need to do on Visualforce Page to connect to Plaid?

I know how to get access token and hit the Api's but don't know the starting mechanism that i need to do on Visualforce.

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar at all with Visualforce, but in general what you need to do is include the Plaid Link component. You can do this with vanilla JavaScript or React. More detailed information is available at https://plaid.com/docs/link/web/

Comment: Thank you so much Alex for your reply..  What happens when I include the "Plaid Link component"? Will it connects to the front end of Plaid?

Comment: Yes. Plaid Link is Plaid's front end UI component and contains all the front end logic you need to get a token that can be exchanged for an access token, which will let you make Plaid API calls.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex... May God bless you !!!

Comment: When clicking on Plaid Link Demo, In User Interface, There is an option as  "Country" ,"Language" and "Product" while launching demo. So, Do i need to create that interface on Front end? or "Plaid Link" includes it?

Comment: @RohanTelang you don't need to create that interface, Plaid will do it for you. When you include Plaid Link, you initialize it with a Link token. The Link token contains all the information that Plaid needs to customize the Link UI. You can create the Link token by calling `/link/token/create`.